# Irrational inequality. Symbolab and Wolfram Alpha have different answers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, irrational-numbers

Question :

Find the solution for x!

$\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x-2}\ge 0$

1. For my own work, i found :

$x<-2 \quad \text{or}\quad  x>2$

2. On Wolfram Alpha app, i type this command

> (sqrt(x^2 - 4))/(x-2)>=0

And give me the answer :

$x=-2 \quad \text{or}\quad  x>2$

3. On symbolab app, it gives me the answer :

$x\le-2 \quad \text{or}\quad  x\ge2$

...........................................................

What is wrong?
Please somebody help me, which one is true? Or what is the correct answer if they all are wrong. And how to do it? Cz i do with basic way for solving this inequality.
Squaring, and define the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square root is always positive or $0$. So the denominator of the fraction $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x-2}\ge 0$ is positive only when $x>2$ (when $x=2$ is impossible). For the numerator, you have to take the C.E. (or existance condition) so $x^2-4\geq 0$: this is true for $x\leq-2$ or $x\geq 2$. Combinig the two condition, I obtain: $x>2$.

Comment: Yes... it makes me clear now.

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{x^2-4}$ is not negative. If it is $0$, the inequality holds; otherwise, the denominator must be positive. By the other hand, $x\neq 2$ to avoid 'division by zero'.

The correct solution is Wolfram Alpha's.

Comment: But if i choose -3 it becomes 9 right? Cz squaring...

Comment: Squaring an inequality does not yield, in general, an equivalent inequality. $$ $$ If $x=-3$, $$\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x-2}=\dfrac{\sqrt 5}{-5}<0$$

Comment: Yeah.. but if somebody asks me how to do it? Wolfram doesn't give me how to do it. Cz i do with basic way for solving this and found the wrong answer. Could you do this if you have idle time please?

Answer (score 2):

$x =-2$ is one solution. For $x \neq -2$ the ratio is positive only when  the denominator is positive.  So $x=-2$ or $x >2$.

Comment: @ajotatxe Thanks. I was correcting my answer when you made the comment.

Comment: Maybe... but how to do it? How do i solve it?

Comment: I just used the fact that if $a \geq 0$ then $\frac a b >0$ iff $b>0$. So consider the cases $\frac a b >0$ and $\frac a b =0$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Wolfram Alpha.  $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x-2}$ is defined when $|x|\ge2$ (because of the numerator)

and $x\ne2$ (because of the denominator).

It is positive when $x>2$ (because then both numerator and denominator are positive),

zero when $x=-2$ (because then numerator is zero and denominator is non-zero),

and negative when $x<-2$ (because then numerator is positive but denominator is negative).

Comment: But if we plug -2 the inequality is incorrect right?

Comment: No, if we let $x=-2$ then   $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x-2}=\dfrac0{-4}=0$, so $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x-2}\ge0$ holds

Comment: Ahh... i didn't notice it..